# Non-Linear Constrained Optimisation Over Zonotopes: Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, numerical-optimization

**Background** I  am  investigating, numerically,  the problem of a chess team attempting to maximise its probability of winning a team match .  Each of our N players independently chooses  one of two strategies , or theoretically  a convex combination of the two, before a move is made. The strategies available for each player depend  on his or her  expected score  against their individual opponent.  The  convex  feasible region is a zonotope,  a vector sum of line segments.  The objective function is  to maximise the  probability of an event, “winning” ,  obtained as the sum of terms from a finite probability generating  function involving N variables and terms of degree at most N.

N even is of most interest. N=2 is solvable analytically. For N =4 , a nightmare scenario does occur , namely of 16 extreme points half are local maxima and half are  local minima.  For N=4,  the vertices  then  naturally  form a bipartite graph of valency  4 with 8 local maxima and 8 local minima.  Ideally I would like to solve problems numerically up to N=16, when I hope Normality will kick in.

One  genetic  algorithm  performs  well compared with for example  Nelder –Mead or Simulated Annealing for N=4.

**Question**  Are there any books or journal articles which consider performance of non-linear constrained optimisation algorithms  over  zonotopes?

Comment: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/test.html

Comment: Thanks very much for doubtless useful link. I will search and study it  , in due course.

Comment: you are welcome